# ¿La carpeta de transitions y anim son lo mismo en Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Lo que pasa es que  quería crear un archivo anim pues para poder hacer animación en mi app de android y al ver varios tutoriales me di cuenta de que se necesita crear un carpeta de tipo anim, pero al yo intentar crearla no me aparecía y en su lugar solo aparecía algo que se asemejaba, que era la carpeta de tipo transition, son las mismas carpetas.

Estoy usando la ultima version de Android Studio (3.0).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El folder de recursos te tipo `transition` como su nombre lo dice es para las transiciones entre vistas y tal. El folder te tipo `anim` es para las animaciones justo como tu lo comentas. Son recursos parecidos, pero no son lo mismo. Ambas se ubican en el folder `res` de tu aplicación.

> "al ver varios tutoriales me di cuenta de que se necesita crear un
>   carpeta de tipo anim, pero al yo intentar crearla no me aparecía"

Android studio tiene un bug en el cual no aparecen algunos folders de recursos al ser creados, intenta refrescar tu proyecto, o incluso cerrarlo y volverlo a abrir.